# How can I beat Hell in the hard mode of Candy Box?

Tags: candy-box

With 100 HP and a level 5 sword, how can I beat the hell level in hard mode? I'm using the Sword of Summoning; would it be better to use the Sword of Fire or the Sword of Life instead?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question, since the strategy for hard mode is significantly different from the normal: you have less HP, a less powerful sword and the demons can quickly kill you if you're not fast enough.

Comment: @Kappei the other question doesn't specify difficulty, therefore this question is a subset of the other one.

Comment: @kotekzot and yet every answer on the other question target specifically normal mode. Soaking up damage in hard mode isn't an option, so I feel there may be the need for a question and relative answers explaining in detail a Hard Mode strategy

Comment: @Kappei just because one doesn't like answers to a question doesn't mean it's ok to ask a duplicate question, that's what comments and bounties are for.

Comment: @kotekzot I raised this question because the other questions and their respective answers talk about HP above 300. In hard mode it does not exist or if there is not figured out how. Not only created the question just because I did not like the answers. I do not think unique, just saw the possibility of another scenario. But one sees that the answers of the other questions are enough for my even being different situations, please tell it clearly.

Comment: @Kappei I agree you. And I think the other people who put +1 also agree too.

Comment: @kotekzot Just because the answers to this question will also answer the other one, the reverse is _not_ true. Check your [deduction logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic#Deductive_and_inductive_reasoning.2C_and_retroductive_inference)...

Comment: @Zommuter a good answer to "how do I do x?" will also answer "how do I do x on hard?".

Answer (score 7):

I assume everyone's problem is with the first part of the wall (with the huge wave of demons).  Assuming you get a decent spawn that lets you maneuver around, you should take only 1-2 attacks from demons before you pop an invulnerability potion (putting you rather low ... 20-30 hp).  Right before you get to a wall, use a seed.  During the seed duration, you should have enough time to heal up with a major health potion.  Once you break through the seed, use another invulnerability potion and you'll be sent back for round two, where you do the same strategy as you did for normal to get through.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike Normal, you will need to rely on the Invulnerability potion to get through the first wave.  Your success will be based purely on the luck of how the Demons are distributed - it took me about 5 reloads on average to punch through to the wall. I also was using a level 5 sword of summoning.

Similar to Normal, you want to be punching through the wall at the second from the bottom door (Which is non-spiked).

Wave 2, use the Imp scroll.

Wave 3, use the Imp scroll, and you may have to use an Acid Rain or Earthquake scroll to survive any fireballs that make it through.

For the Devil, you will need to use a Fire Scroll on top of the invulnerability potion - you won't do enough damage with just the sword to kill him in the duration of the potion, and teleporting back will put you in harms way of the fireballs.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely the most difficult level. Good news: it will be much easier after you make it.

I believe you have an armour and a magical horn already. You should have!

First stage - this is the most difficult part. Use invulnerability to get to the wall (it's easy to say). Attack the wall in a second row from the bottom, or the wall will kill you!!! Seriously: this is the most important information: a second wall from bottom will not kill you! You don't need invulnerability to destroy the wall! When you destroy the wall, use a seed just before teleporting gate! Remember, you can keep using seeds to stay in the same spot as long as you want - take a breath, clear you mind, let the magical horn to run. If you came so far, the rest is a piece of cake (chocolate cake).

Second stage - do not try to bypass enemies, do not go up or down - just go straight in the row you are (second row from the bottom, as I suggested). Remember: ghosts (GHO) halves your life, but does not kill you if you have magical horn. Use Earthquake or Acid rain if you want to clear your path (ghost still slows you down). One scroll kills all ghosts in your row. You do not need to use a seed on the end, because you don't need to recover your health (really, you don't need more then 4 health on this point).

Third stage - very similar to second stage. Do not do up or down. Use Earthquake or Acid rain to clear your path - you want to reach the wall before the fireballs start running. Alternatively use invulnerability, so fireball won't kill you. You can use seed just before the devil (make some space, or devil will destroy it) and recover your health with magical horn or health scroll (I found out that this is not necessary, since you can kill the devil in time of one invulnerability potion). Kill the devil (use invulnerability potion, fire scroll helps as well). I guess, The Sword of Flames is profitable on this stage (actually I always choose The Sword of Flames, so I'm not sure if you can kill devil so easy with other swords ... I will try today maybe).

Answer (score -2):

1. Beat Hell in normal mode
2. Save
3. Go back to hard mode
4. DONE!
5. (Its that easy)

Comment: This doesn't at all answer what the asker really wants.

Answer (score -2):

use all pain au chocolat to reduce spells countdown (2s is enough to beat the evil)Jump infinately with the rocket boots to  go in top of screen , when in the middle of the map , summon the demon wall , wait 1-2s then use teleport to go back at start of the map , repeat this step infinately , congratulation , you killed the devil in hard

Comment: This answer is for candy box 2, the question is for version 1.